# Do a linq query on an object array?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a collection of type objects which I know they are type Employee. I'd like to perform some linq operations on them using the employee some thing similar to this:

```
 var options = (from e in m_Employees  
                      select (e as Employee).DepartmentCode).Distinct();
```

But the as employee is not surprisingly giving an error. is there a way around it?

Changing the collection is not really an options since I,m maintaining the code and I want to avoid big changes.

Comment: What error? Runtime or compile time?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use either

```
from e in m_Employees.Cast<Employee>()
    select e.DepartmentCode
```

or

```
from e in m_Employees.OfType<Employee>()
    select e.DepartmentCode
```

`Cast` thows an error if you can not cast each item to `Employee`, but `OfType` will filter out those objects not matching the type.

Comment: Note that a neater way of expressing a call to `Cast<T>` in a query expression is to specify the type of the range variable explicitly.

Answer (score 6):

Rather than using `as Employee` it would be better to make the compiler basically insert a call to `Cast<T>` using an explicitly typed range variable:

```
var options = (from Employee e in m_Employees
               select e.DepartmentCode).Distinct();
```

Or alternatively and equivalently:

```
var options = m_Employees.Cast<Employee>()
                         .Select(e => e.DepartmentCode)
                         .Disinct();
```

However, I still wouldn't have expected your original code to fail, if the array really *does* only include `Employee` references... If you were getting a `NullReferenceException` then *either* one of the values was null, *or* it was a non-null reference to a non-Employee object. These will both still give you an error with the above code, but you'll be able to see which one based on whether you still get a `NullReferenceException` or an `InvalidCastException`.

In general you should only use `as` when you're going to use the result conditionally. If you're *sure* that every value is really of the right type, you should use a cast instead - so that if you're wrong, you'll get the code blowing up with an exception instead of propagating a null reference to the rest of the code, where it could cause harm later on and make it hard to spot the source of the error.

If you were getting a compile-time error then there are a number of possible causes, based on what exception you were seeing.

EDIT: Okay, so it was an `IEnumerable` causing a compile-time error... `Cast<T>()` and `OfType<T>()` are both extension methods on just `IEnumerable` instead of on `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: Why do you think his code should have worked? The reason he is "casting" seems to be that he is using an untyped data source (`IEnumerable`) as pointed out in my answer. In that case, his code is simply illegal.

Comment: @Daniel: I think "seems to be" is an overstatement. It could well have been an `object[]` or something similar (`object[]` sounds pretty likely based on the question title). But yes, if it's an untyped collection that would explain it. Basically we don't know...

Comment: It is an untyped collection, the error I was getting was Argument type 'string' is not assignable to parameter type 'TResult' But both answers fixed the problem. Thanks

Comment: @Marcom: In future then, please tell us what the error is, instead of leaving us guessing.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be:

```
(from e in m_Employees
let x = e as Employee
select x.DepartmentCode).Distinct();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
var options = (from e in m_Employees.Cast<Employee>()
               select e.DepartmentCode).Distinct();
```

The important part is the `Cast<Employee>`. My answer assumes that `m_Employees` is an `IEnumerable` like `ArrayList` instead of an `IEnumerable<Employee>` like `List<Employee>`.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
var options = m_Employees
        .Cast<Employee>()
        .Select(item => item.DepartmentCode)
        .Distinct();
```